# Is there an option to tell Magento to keep old compiled JS/CSS assets?

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.13

We're noticing an issue where, due to our caching scheme (using external services like CloudFlare), old compiled assets are deleted from our server - ie a merged JS file with a generated hash as the filename. Sometimes this causes clients to no longer be able to see the assets and the site functionality diminishes. We're using 1.13.*. Is there a way to tell Magento to keep old asset files when it generates new ones?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the function that starts the removal of the merged JS and CSS files is called `cleanMergedJsCss` located in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php`. You'll need to override that class to change the function.

---

Start by creating `app/etc/modules/Magentose_Keepassets.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
      <modules>
           <Magentose_Keepassets>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
           </Magentose_Keepassets>
      </modules>
 </config>
```

Create the path & file: `app/code/local/Magentose/Keepassets/etc/config.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <config>
           <modules>
                <Magentose_Keepassets>
                     <version>1.0.0</version>
                </Magentose_Keepassets>
           </modules>
           <global>
                <models>
                     <magentose_keepassets>
                          <class>Magentose_Keepassets_Model</class>
                     </magentose_keepassets>
                     <core>
                          <rewrite>
                               <design_package>Magentose_Keepassets_Model_Design_Package</design_package>
                          </rewrite>
                     </core>
                </models>
           </global>
      </config>
```

Create the path & file: `app/code/local/Magentose/Keepassets/Model/Design/Package.php`

```
 <?php

 class Magentose_Keepassets_Model_Design_Package extends Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package
 {

      // To stop Magento from deleting the old files, change the second argument in the calls to _initMergerDir to false. 

      public function cleanMergedJsCss()
      {
         $result = (bool)$this->_initMergerDir('js', false);
         $result = (bool)$this->_initMergerDir('css', false) && $result;
         return (bool)$this->_initMergerDir('css_secure', false) && $result;
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, by default magento uses a hash of the included file name to generate the merged js/css file name. Therefore if you haven't add, remove or change any of files then the merged js/css files will retain the same name. Shouldn't the file remain on your cdn until you purge it?

You could create a custom module to change this behavior

/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/CacheController.php

```
// clean javascript/css cache
 if ($this->getRequest()->getPost('jscss_action')) {
        if (Mage::getDesign()->cleanMergedJsCss()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('The JavaScript/CSS cache has been cleared.')
            );
        } else {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Failed to clear the JavaScript/CSS cache.'));
        }
    }
```

/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php

```
/**
 * Remove all merged js/css files
 *
 * @return  bool
 */
public function cleanMergedJsCss()
{
    $result = (bool)$this->_initMergerDir('js', true);
    $result = (bool)$this->_initMergerDir('css', true) && $result;
    return (bool)$this->_initMergerDir('css_secure', true) && $result;
}

/**
 * Make sure merger dir exists and writeable
 * Also can clean it up
 *
 * @param string $dirRelativeName
 * @param bool $cleanup
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _initMergerDir($dirRelativeName, $cleanup = false)
{
    $mediaDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
    try {
        $dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $dirRelativeName;
        if ($cleanup) {
            Varien_Io_File::rmdirRecursive($dir);
            Mage::helper('core/file_storage_database')->deleteFolder($dir);
        }
        if (!is_dir($dir)) {
            mkdir($dir);
        }
        return is_writeable($dir) ? $dir : false;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
    return false;
}
```